# Запуск исполняемого файла на чистой машине (С++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, консоль, сборка

В общем нужно было написать консольное приложение состоящее из нескольких функций. Писал в Visual studio 15 (С++). Нужно решение прислать человеку в виде исходников и исполняемого файла.

Исполняемый файл должен запускаться на чистой (!) машине, т.е. к нему должны быть предоставлены dll.

К исходникам должно быть описание как и чем собирать(что надо делать?Что есть исходники?). dll из функций вроде бы сделал, но не запускается на машине, где нет VCredist(vcruntime140.dll). Это решаемо вообще, без установки, но как остальное, я не знаю, глупый вопрос, но он ставит меня в тупик.

Comment: Что-то не так. "*dll из функций вроде бы сделал*" - вот это зачем вообще?

Comment: Исполняемый файл должен запускаться на чистой (!) машине, т.е. к нему должны быть предоставлены dll ... вот для этого

Comment: Ещё раз, по буквам: зачем *внутренние* функции программы выносить в отдельные dll? То что вы говорите - чушь какая-то, не имеющая смысла. Явно тут речь идёт о каких-то *внешних* зависимостях, которые *могут* встретиться (а могут и нет, тогда никаких dll прилагать и не нужно)

Comment: Ну хорошо..основная проблема в том, что не запускается на нулевой машине без vcruntime140.dll..что с этим делать?

Comment: Очевидно, 1) приложить эту самую dll, или 2) переписать так, чтобы избавиться от зависимости (тут никаких конкретных советов быть не может без изучения исходников), или 3) попробовать собрать программу на целевой машине

Comment: Линкуйте все статически, и будет один exe файл автономный. (c++ - Code Generation - Runtime Library - Multi threaded)

Comment: Спасибо multi threaded действительно помогло!

Answer (score 2):

Собирайте со статическим связыванием библиотек (/MT в командной строке, в свойствах проекта - создание кода->библиотека времени выполнения->многопоточная).