# Как запустить код c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Я учусь кодить, и на этом заказе появились проблемы. У меня часть кода, которую надо запустить в виде приложения (.exe), но я не понимаю как это сделать. От меня требуется сделать приложение, которое мог бы запустить любой пользователь windowns просто его скачав.
Как???код индентичен этому

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int a, b = 17;
    std::cout << "Введите альфу\n";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << '\n' << b - a;
}
```

Comment: Вас интересует [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/535736/195342)?

Answer (score -1):

Я написал код в  файлах ресурсов, и использовал через папку release.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт..